# How to properly access an object nested inside parent object to use it as a type for parameter of a method nested in other object of a said parent

Tags: typescript, object, types, casting, reference

I have such code:

```
type GenericFunction = (...args: [Map<string, boolean | number | string>, number, string]) => void;

interface GenericObject { [key: string]: boolean | GenericFunction | number | string | GenericObject };

const API: GenericObject = {};
```

Later in code, I'll add some other objects, fill them with properties and values and nest them inside the parent `API` object.

One of said nested objects, has a proeprty value being JS method:

```
API.json.mfa.AuthenticateRequest = (
  username: string,
  password: string,
  cardNumber: string,
  loginType: API.json.player.core.LoginType
): void => {
  const self = this;
  ...
};
```

The `loginType` parameter should be of `LoginType` type.

The nested `LoginType` type is object of value:

```
API.json.player.core.LoginType = {
  MANUAL_LOGIN: 'MANUAL_LOGIN',
  CARDED_LOGIN: 'CARDED_LOGIN',
  CARDLESS_CONNECT_LOGIN: 'CARDLESS_CONNECT_LOGIN',
};
```

Too bad, the reference to the `LoginType` in this `loginType` parameter of a method, causes error in IntelliJ IDEA: `TS2503: Cannot find namespace API`.

So the `API` part in `loginType: API.json.player.core.LoginType` is underscored in red, as a error causing code.

How to reference properly from within parameter, to this `LoginType` object, and use it as a type?

Or maybe do I need to declare a constant and initialize it with value: `const LoginType = API.json.player.core.LoginType;`?

And then export it as a type, somehow?

Tried this:
`const LoginType = API.json.player.core.LoginType;`
and changed from reference to nested object to just constant name:

```
(
  username: string,
  password: string,
  cardNumber: string,
  loginType: LoginType,
  egmId: string
)
```

but IntelliJ now shows error `TS2749: LoginType refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`.

I made a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgMQK7zcFA9vFALxQAUAdNQIZIDmAzgFxQDaAsjWADyPCp49ADRQARgQIAbCDWIAfKPCwBbMciiL%20g%20gD5RytclHaUQgLoBKUrqgA3AigAmAbgBQbs8GQAzGmmg4RFQ0AHkxACsIPCgAb3YAawgQVlMLVglpWQUlVXUkTSg0%20kKg5HRsXHwiUoRysMjo4CgAX3dPeG8kPwCoAEEwFEq8QmIIAA9veCdGWDqQ4eriWLcoNahuFAA1ZEZR1IEzend1qBUIRkYaeggAFXAIA50T9fPL64gASSdWQ3yXtZIC5gIiMR5FQ5CAFFCDADgXK43b6sRajaFg4AAJWBoPBqKI0KwYKQ8Bo5yeR2hYBolwA7gQkD8Ic9Vus0HQnAA5PLIClQ1lrKQEehme6QVigSAEHxQAAywtFD2hEHoKmRzMpbjaHjQoOa8pF8DF0DIKzWHD6nIAqn1ZQB9WWhGCfTmsADkFuttodTpdbuErIAwn1MQARACioZ9ztdUDdwbDkejfoDawTodl4YAylm7YHQpzOeHA7dk7H4yGM9nc-nC8XS46Y-6tRtZmUQuEonh2rr4Px%20gAFT6sdvoTtNUhxbVuPpDygRRg1U0tVtzYJjxrdmdzhdESgqPyT2Irmlr%20rjrezz7zxfwShgKQ0EAaZer0cNLvAdxXm97h9P5BKF1IEjxPNt5g3T92h-Xc7wPGhKD6LBgAACwQfB2W8bEAEcsAuZoyB8HARhqcgBSgVCUBYfpBnxeBU3WIlkFJckNSEBi1mpOkGSZYoOKgdlGW5IwkD5ERyKFQ1jVYGDb3vR9nyQICGQgSgDUVSB%20JVNVeMheg3EsVgHGcOJWV7fswSkGUyEoxgXgAensoozACVgAEZKAABlZWzKE2HYkD2Jc4w8gBWABaLNOVnLMAAlQluN0HKcvZcHBDzvLWXy3kRO4HknN0kNQ9D0BoLCIFw-CktZRznLS9yvJ8lCqMoDF4XeJEnEncgco%20dU-mQQz7EcLqSFsM11ksnx9wRPrRrOWbOpebU1lq1LXKgDKmpajFsUYEE%20xNCggX23ExKG4zRvG8ipsoE6DrBSd7txZbkrqjawu2xhKCYkkySO36WIgN71vSyhQq%20%208aUYelGUnLiYZ4kGXLBiGsua77BK5HkCjILHhP%20GqUpRhq0YojHKEkjSjqpo0lSJ97Uch7TvknFnXBbU8cASeACFpYhT3fOjoJ3OT-0U5SgTUhU6cgI9WU9G17UbF13UV70Vc5Zs00rJNNfddM9d9LWGPTTMczzAsixLMsDcrc2ayt%20sy2bMCzw7TcvyAA) based on what @jcalz already did:

```
type GenericFunction = (...args: [Map<string, boolean | number | string>, number, string]) => void;

interface GenericObject { [key: string]: boolean | number | string | GenericFunction | GenericObject };

interface ApiFunction extends GenericFunction {
    apiVersion: string;
    messageType: string;
    messageId: number;
    response: string;
    setMessageId: Function;
    setResponse: Function;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    cardNumber: string;
    loginType: typeof LoginType;
    egmId: string;
};

const LoginType = {
  MANUAL_LOGIN: 'MANUAL_LOGIN',
  CARDED_LOGIN: 'CARDED_LOGIN',
  CARDLESS_CONNECT_LOGIN: 'CARDLESS_CONNECT_LOGIN',
} as GenericObject;

const API: GenericObject = {};

API.json = {} as GenericObject;
API.json.mfa = {} as GenericObject;
API.json.player = {} as GenericObject;
API.json.player.core = {} as GenericObject;

API.json.mfa.AuthenticateRequest = function (
    this: ApiFunction,
    username: string,
    password: string,
    cardNumber: string,
    loginType: API.json.player.core.LoginType,
    egmId: string
): void {
  const self = this;
  // since: 1.0
  this.apiVersion = '1.5-SNAPSHOT';
  // since: 1.0
  this.messageType = 'AuthenticateRequest';
  // since: 1.0
  this.setMessageId = (messageId: number): void => {
    self.messageId = messageId;
  };
  // since: 1.0
  this.setResponse = (response: string): void => {
    self.response = response;
  };
  // since: 1.5
  this.username = username;
  // since: 1.5
  this.password = password;
  // since: 1.5
  this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
  // since: 1.5
  this.loginType = loginType;
  // since: 1.5
  this.egmId = egmId;
} as unknown as GenericFunction;

API.json.player.core.LoginType = {
  MANUAL_LOGIN: 'MANUAL_LOGIN',
  CARDED_LOGIN: 'CARDED_LOGIN',
  CARDLESS_CONNECT_LOGIN: 'CARDLESS_CONNECT_LOGIN',
} as GenericObject;
```

Comment: You can probably write `typeof API.json.player.core.LoginType` or `(typeof API)["json"]["player"]["core"]["LoginType"]`, but without a [mre] of your issue that's just a guess we can't verify (right now `API` has type `any` which my IDE can't not "pay attention" to, unfortunately). Could you please [edit] to make your issue reproducible by others?  It can be a toy example that's only nested one or two properties deep.

Comment: Edited, maybe now you'll be able to reproduce it?

Comment: No, [there are still unrelated errors](https://tsplay.dev/WkaLJN).  Could you fix those?

Comment: I did a [fix which is on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQJovN) already.

Comment: But now your type is just `GenericObject` because you created it that way.  I can fix those errors like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDgolw) but I have no idea if that's what you're looking for.  If you can [edit] to make the example more minimal (fewer sibling properties and shallower nesting and fewer irrelevant `// since: 1.0` comments) maybe I'll understand it more?  If not maybe someone else will be able to help.  Good luck!